# Como mandar datos ingresados a un TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando crear una aplicacion a base de un ejercicio, en la aplicacion se deben ingresar dos numeros enteros, a partir de estos dos numeros enteros se debe calcular: El numero menor, la cantidad de pares entre los dos numeros y la suma total de todos los numeros entre el mayor y el menor, estas opciones estaran en un spinner y dependiendo de la opcion seleccionada deberia dar el resultado indicado, mi problema es que no se como imprimir esos resultados en un  `TextView` , por ahora estoy mostrando los datos con un `Toast` para saber que la aplicacion funciona, pero no se como mandar los datos al TextView

```
package com.example.ejercicio1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnMostrar;
    private EditText edt1,edt2; // edt1=Pimer numero entero ingresado edt2=segundo.
    private TextView tvMostrar;
    private Spinner spOp; //Spinner con las opciones

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnMostrar=findViewById(R.id.btn_mostrar);
        edt1=findViewById(R.id.edt_1);
        edt2=findViewById(R.id.edt_2);
        tvMostrar=findViewById(R.id.tv_mostrar);
        spOp=findViewById(R.id.sp_ope);
        String[] x={"","Valor Menor","Numeros Pares","Suma total"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,x);
        spOp.setAdapter(adapter);
        String ax="";
        btnMostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    int n1=Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());
                    int n2=Integer.parseInt(edt2.getText().toString());
                    String opcion = spOp.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    if (opcion.equals(""))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Seleccione una opcion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String ax="";
                        Metodos x=new Metodos();
                        int resultado=0;
                        if (opcion.equals("Valor Menor"))
                        {
                            resultado=x.NumeroMenor(n1,n2);                 // de la linea 51 a la 55 es un intento de imprimir los datos en el EditText
                            ax = ax + "El resultado es :" + resultado;
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "El numero menor es " + resultado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else if (opcion.equals("Numeros Pares"))
                        {
                            resultado=x.Pares(n1,n2);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "La cantidad de numeros pares es "+resultado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            resultado=x.SumaTotal(n1,n2);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "La suma total los numeros es "+resultado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    tvMostrar.setText(ax);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException ex)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Debe Ingresar un numero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });




    }
}
```

Tengo los metodos aca

```
package com.example.ejercicio1;

public class Metodos {
    public int NumeroMenor(int a, int b) {
        if (a < b)
            return a;
        else
            return b;
    }
    public int Pares (int a,int b) {
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                contador++;
        }return contador;
    }
    public int SumaTotal (int a,int b) {
        int suma = 0;
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            suma = suma + i;
        }return suma;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al obtener el resultado, como es un valor tipo `Int`, lo debes convertir a tipo `String` (usa `String.valueOf()`) para poder definirlo en el `TextView`, ejemplo:

```
resultado=x.NumeroMenor(n1,n2);  
...
...
tvMostrar.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
```